# “In the outskirts” versus “on the outskirts”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following sentences is correct, and why?

> I bought a house *in* the outskirts of the city.
>   I bought a house *on* the outskirts of the city.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual idiom is "**on** the outskirts". Don't ask why, it's an idiom.

[image: ngram of on vs. in]

Answer (score 7):

As Martha's NGram shows, *on the outskirts* is the prevailing choice between the two.

Why should this be? Well IMO it is down to people's underlying understanding of what the 
phrase means. You know what the outskirts are, even if you don't know why.

Here's a short etymology for [outskirt](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=outskirt&searchmode=none) from Etymonline

> "outer border," 1590s, from out + skirt (q.v.). Now only in plural. Originally in Spenser.

and in this instance skirt means a border or edge. If you live on the outskirts you live on the outer *edge*. You can't live *in* an edge.

So while it's not wrong to say *in the outskirts*, since these days it pertains to an area rather than an edge, the underlying meaning of the phrase has persisted in our psyches (according to Martha's NGram) and so we prefer that one overall.

Answer (score -1):

Either is technically a correct sentence.

> I bought a house **on** the outskirts of the city

is best because "on" gives the sense that the house is farther away from the city.